# tcl array key with meta characters not working

Tags: tcl

if i use a key like "int_size[1]" in tcl array - i am unable to get the value by using "array get array key".

```
array set mymap {}
set key "int_size"
set mymap($key) 100
if {[array get mymap $key] == ""} {
   puts "Error: $key not found"
} else {
  puts "Ok: $key found"
}

set key {int_size[1]}
set mymap($key) 100
if {[array get mymap $key] == ""} {
  puts "Error: $key not found"
} else {
  puts "Ok: $key found"
}
```

shows below output

```
Ok: int_size found  
Error: int_size[1] not found
```

Comment: Try comparing with $mymap($key) instead of array get mymap $key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array get` command takes a glob pattern (as in `string match`), and `[`…`]` is special to globbing patterns. You can fix this by adding backslashes (perhaps with `string map`), but it's really working very hard for not much benefit.

Instead, test if the value is present using `info exists`. That works for all keys, and (from 8.5 onwards) is very efficient. Well, it's more efficient than `array get` in all versions, since that does a linear scan of the entire array internally.

```
if {[info exists mymap($key)]} {
    puts "OK, $key found"
} else {
    puts "Error, $key absent"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array index should always be a proper list (it isn't actually documented that way, but it sort of follows from the semantics of the array command). Since the string "int_size[1]" isn't a proper list, it won't work unless forced with array(index) syntax. When in doubt, wrap the value in [list ...] before assigning it to the key variable.

**ETA**

The advice above is correct and useful, but it's Donal's answer that is most relevant. I would have mentioned that bit too except that after all these years, I don't seem to be able to Freaking. Remember. That array get takes a glob string.